# Simple application of Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Problem 11.4.2 Arfken
>
> Evaluate $\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2-1}$, where $C$ is the circle $|z-1||=1$.

My approach to the solution is that to express the integral as partial fractions.

$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^2-1}=\frac12 \oint_C ( \frac1{z-1} - \frac1{z+1} ) dz$. Since the point $z=1$ is within the contour, and $z=-1$ is outside the contour, using Cauchy's Integral Formula, one gets $\pi i$. But the answer in the instructor's manual is $0$. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: The answer given [here](http://theory.uchicago.edu/~liantaow/my-teaching/ps3_soln.pdf) is also $i\pi$.

Comment: using Cauchy integral's formula and Cauchy integral's theorem. Otherwise you can write $\frac{1}{z^2-1} = \frac{1/(z+1)}{z-1}$ And your result is correct.

Comment: Thanks. The solution manual needs a revision then. Residues too gives me $\pi i$.